# Не работает MySQLi PhP 8.1 Apache2

Tags: php, apache, mysqli, apache2

Пытаюсь подключиться к базе данных. Позже ниже вывожу данные о таблице Posts

Код:

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect(// тут данные ( они валидные ) );
if (!$connect) {
    echo 'Error';
}
if ($connect) {
    echo 'Ready';
}
$posts = mysqli_query($connect, 'SELECT * FROM default_db.posts');

print_r($posts);
?>
```

Пробовал много чего, не работает!

Консоль: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1OAF.png)

WebStorm: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDUH5.png)

Источники/индекс: [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUZrg.png)

Установлено: PhP 8.1; Apache2l; php-mysql

Когда вывожу phpinfo() все работает: [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugVJF.png)

Comment: столько скриншотов и ни одного нужного))) Для начала посмотрите в логи апача, на каком файле и что вызвало ошибку 500

Comment: как минимум: на скриншоте `phpinfo` модуль 'mysqli` отсутствует

Comment: Поддерживаю Диму, вопрос не даёт вообще никаких мыслей... Логи или хотя-бы ошибку E_ALL

Comment: Дмитрий, файлов больше нету. Только index.php

Comment: Подскажите тогда как его установить, пытался через sudo apt-get install php8.1-mysql